How to use an image to upload multiple files in LWC?
I'm using input type=file because lightning-input won't allow to be replaced by an image. I need the user to be able to upload multiple files by either clicking the image, or by dragging and dropping the files.
I watched a tutorial but it used jquery (I'm not familiar with it) when I implemented it in my lwc, it just doesn't work. (I have no logs or something that can be useful)
html:
<template>
      <div class="custom-upload" id="fileDropArea">
                  <img data-id="imagePreview" src={fileUpload} width="700" height="500"/>
                  <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" onchange={handleFileChange} multiple></input>
              </div>
              <span class="required-file" data-id="chosen-file">{chosenFileName}</span>
</template>

js:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import dropFile from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/FileDropHere";
import uploadFile from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/FileUpload";
import JQUERY from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jqueryLibrary'; 

export default class SSC_FilesUpload extends LightningElement {
    jQueryInitialized = false;
    fileUpload = uploadFile;
    filedrop = dropFile;
    chosenFileName = 'No file chosen';
    fileUploadElement;
    imagePreviewElement;

       // Lifecycle hook to load jQuery
       renderedCallback() {
        if (this.jQueryInitialized) {
            return;
        }

        // Dynamically load jQuery
        loadScript(this, JQUERY)
            .then(() => {
                this.jQueryInitialized = true;  // Mark jQuery as initialized
                this.initializeJQuery();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error loading jQuery:', error);
            });
    }

    // Initialize jQuery functionality
    initializeJQuery() {
        // Get elements from the shadow DOM using LWC specific querying
        const fileUploadElement = this.template.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
        const imagePreview = this.template.querySelector('img[data-id="imagePreview"]');
        const chosenFileElement = this.template.querySelector('span[data-id="chosen-file"]');
        const customUploadLabel = this.template.querySelector('.custom-upload');

        // File input change handler
        $(fileUploadElement).on('change', function () {
            const file = this.files[0];
            displayImage(file);
        });

        // Prevent default drag behaviors
        ['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
            $(customUploadLabel).on(eventName, preventDefaults);
        });

        // Highlight drop area when item is dragged over it
        ['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(eventName => {
            $(customUploadLabel).on(eventName, highlight);
        });

        ['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
            $(customUploadLabel).on(eventName, unhighlight);
        });

        // Handle dropped files
        $(customUploadLabel).on('drop', function (e) {
            const dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
            const files = dt.files;
            if (files.length) {
                fileUploadElement.files = files;
                displayImage(files[0]);
            }
        });

        // Prevent default actions for drag-and-drop events
        function preventDefaults(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }

        // Highlight the drop area
        function highlight() {
            $(customUploadLabel).css('border-color', '#666');  // Customize the color
        }

        // Remove highlight from the drop area
        function unhighlight() {
            $(customUploadLabel).css('border-color', '#ccc');  // Reset color to default
        }

        // Display image preview and file name
        function displayImage(file) {
            if (file && file.type.startsWith('image/')) {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $(imagePreview).attr('src', e.target.result);
                    $(imagePreview).show();
                    $(chosenFileElement).text(file.name);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
                $(chosenFileElement).text('No file chosen');
                $(imagePreview).hide();
            }
        }
    }
}

css:
.required-file::after {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
}

.custom-upload {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
}

input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}

.imagePreview {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
}


Maybe I don't fully understand your requirements. Anyway, you may try using lightning-file-upload lightning tag (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation). To replace the Upload button with some image you may create a static resource containing a css file and then load it into LWC connectedCallback using loadStyle method (here you can find documentation and an example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation). In that static resource file you will have to play a bit with CSS of lightning-file-upload component:

You will need to set "display: none" to two inner span tags which contain the button label and drag'n'drop label.
You will need to define next attributes to your inner label tag:


cursor: pointer;
background-size: cover;
width: [YOUR_PREFERED_WIDTH]px;
height: [YOUR_PREFERED_HEIGHT]px;
background-image: url(LINK_TO_NEEDED_IMAGE);

As a result, you will have an image which will play a role both of an upload button and a drag'n'drop area:


import jquery from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jquery';
@track uploadFiles = [];
@track domainUrl= '';//APEX URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
handleFileChange(event){
    const files = event.target.files;
    if(files) {
        let tempFile = {};
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            tempFile.base64 = e.target.result;
            reader = null;
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        tempFile.Title = file.name;
        tempFile.uuid = this.guid();

        this.uploadFiles.push(tempFile);
    }
}

async createVersions() {
    const uploadUrl = this.domainUrl+'/services/data/v60.0/sobjects/ContentVersion';
    for (let file of this.uploadFiles) {
        await $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: uploadUrl,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'Title': file.Title,
                'VersionData': this.arrayBufferToBase64(file.base64 == '' ? '1' : file.base64),
                "PathOnClient": file.Title
            }),
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + {{sessionId}},
                "content-Type": 'application/json'
            },
            xhr: function () {
                let myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) {
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
                        var loaded = e.loaded;
                        var total = e.total;
                        var percent = Math.floor(100 * loaded / total);
                        that.percent = percent;
                        console.log(percent,' percent');
                    }, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.success){
                    // data.id is VersionId
                }else{
                    
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                
            }
        });
    }
}

arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);

    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
}

guid() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
            v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });
}


each file need less than 37MB

Need to add explaination that how this answer solve the problem asked into the question.

Downvoted because this is just a code dump. There is no explanation as to how it works or how this resolves the problem this question is about. You should [edit] your answer to add an explanation.
